Unable to authenticate with Office365 IMAP mailbox using XOAUTH2 in NodeJS
I've built a system in NodeJS to listen to IMAP for emails, it's was working fine with an AWS Workmail test email (Basic auth), however our organisation uses Office 365 with MFA so I've had to update the authentication to use XOAUTH2
I've setup an application in Entra and built a test app to generate an auth token.
Generating an auth token works fine, and I then attempt to connect to the IMAP server.
However I get an 'A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed' error from the Imap module.
There are no Entra sign in logs when I try to connect to IMAP (there are for the MFA flow to generate the token)
I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to look next, I've tried different scopes, different accounts, I even started writing my own Imap connection module from scratch just using TLS.
The fact that there are no sign-in logs in Entra makes me wonder if the auth request isn't even reaching MS or the request itself is invalid but the response from the Imap server seems to simply be 'Authenticate failed'.
Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
The process I've used to generate the token is as follows. Based on this article on MS Learn.
Create app in Entra
Use the msal-node library to getAuthCodeUrl
Authenticate through generated authURl
Get the token using aquireTokenByCode
Store the token and generate the base64 xoauth2 string.
Pass this string to IMAP package
Scopes requested:

offline_access
https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All

Below is my Imap configuration - I'm using the mail-listener5 package, which is a wrapper around the imap module.
async function run() {
    //read the token from the txt file
    const token = await fs.promises.readFile('./token.txt')
    //generate the xoauth2 string
    const authString = ("user=" + config.emailParser.address + "^Aauth=Bearer " + token + "^A^A")
    const authBuffer = Buffer.from(authString).toString('base64');

    const mailListener = new MailListener({
        xoauth2: authBuffer,
        host: config.emailParser.host,
        port: 993,
        tls: true
    });

    mailListener.start();
}

Thank you for your time, and appreciate any tips.
